# How to read the output on command prompt while executing in RUNAS mode from java program

Tags: java, cmd, runas

Is there any way to read the output(the result generated) from command prompt while executing the command in RUNAS mode. I am using java ProcessBuilder to execute the command and using [LSRUNAS](http://www.moernaut.com/default.aspx?item=lsrunas) utility to run command with admin creds. But the issue is that this opens a new command window from which i am unable to read the result. Its very easy to read the result generated in the same window by using the inputstream of the executed process but i am not able to figure out how can we do it from the new opened command window. Is it even possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Consider redirecting the output to a file in the temp directory, then loading that after execution has finished.

Comment: HI @Scott, i tried that already but it doesn't work as the RUNAS command launches a new shell.